# Scroll event not executing when scrolled object is not part of the initial DOM

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a fixed DIV containing some scrolled overflow stuff. I want to start learning about scrolling, parallax, etc... and first of all I need to be able to detect whether the user is scrollong this DIV.

I created this code, and simply no alert appears:

```
$(document).on('scroll','.contentPanel',function(){
   alert('YIKES!');
});
```

I tried also variations like:

```
$('.contentPanel').parent().on('scroll','.contentPanel',function(){
   alert('YIKES!');
});
```

This `.contentpanel` is NOT part of the initial DOM, and to check this I have tested succesfuly this function (which means that it is able to detect clicks on it but not scrolls):

```
$(document).on('click','.contentPanel',function(){
   alert('dlick');
});
```

But direct events DO NOT work on my docuyment, such as .scroll or .click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse wheel event is different across browsers, here is an example to get the right event.

```
var mouseWheelEvent = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"; //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) { //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting) 
    document.attachEvent("on"+mouseWheelEvent, function(e) {
        var event = window.event || e;
    });
} else if (document.addEventListener) { //WC3 browsers 
    document.addEventListener(mouseWheelEvent, function(e) {
        var event = window.event || e;
    }, false);
}
```

You might wanna look at this question I answered earlier: [Scrolling a Div from Anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834324/scrolling-a-div-from-anywhere/24890325#24890325)

**EDIT**

```
var mouseWheelEvent = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"; //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) { //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting) 
    document.attachEvent("on"+mouseWheelEvent, scrollHandler);
} else if (document.addEventListener) { //WC3 browsers 
    document.addEventListener(mouseWheelEvent, scrollHandler, false);
}

function scrollHandler(e) {
    if( $('.contentPanel').is(':hover') ) {
        alert('whatup');   
    }
}
```

This works fine, jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4767/

Comment: this is helpful, thank you, but from my firefox I can execute scroll events on jsfiddle, so theorically there's no reason for it not to work with the same function on my document, isnt it?

Comment: Ah I see, you can however check if you are hovering over your div when the document is scrolled. That's probably what you want.

Comment: Here you have the project under construction: after waiting for load and clicking the intro, .contentPanel (the  bottom big part of the table) does not generate any alert when scrolling: http://germanalvarez.net/5/

Comment: @Biomehanika edited my answer for you, this should work. I must add, nice effects you got going there on your site, impressive!

Comment: YES!! I am about to study hard that piece of code and your link, must undertand this. Very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/nyCKE/4765/

```
$('.contentPanel').scroll(function () {
    alert('YIKES!');
});
```

Comment: That works on JSFIDDLE but not on my project, because direct events are not recognised in here (for example, see this fiddle; this neither works on my document but it does on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4766/

Comment: Do you have a link to your document? it should work if it does in JSFiddle. Also remember to put your jQuery Code in $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Comment: I did not put that code, I will see if that's the problem, but I guess that the problem is the imposibility of adding direct events such as ".scroll" or ".click".. all must be added trough a ".on" event, because .contenPanel is not part of the initial DOM. I can make a .on('click', function....) work, but not a .click(function...), so the same is happening with .scroll but .on('scroll', function...) is neither working grrr...

Comment: I will try to upload and give you the link

Comment: here you have: http://germanalvarez.net/5/  please note this is under construction. last function on functions.js is the one that is not working. thanks!